# Using dladdr in release

Tags: c++, c, xcode, gcc, clang

Im writing a profiling tool for my App and im using dladdr to convert function pointer to name. Everything work fine as long as Im in debug but as soon as I compile in release (using XCode 5.1) all name conversion fail and return NULL ex:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    Dl_info info;

    if( dladdr( main, &info ) != 0 )
    { fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", info.dli_sname ); }
```

I tried multiple compiler flags that I pass to the C/C++ Flags: -export-dynamic -fPIC as well as -Wl,--export-dynamic nothing works... Is there a way to still compile with optimization and retain the function address -> name translation functionalities of dladdr?

Comment: Have you tried adding -rdynamic as a linker option?

Comment: Arrgg... that's it! I tried -rdynamic but I put it in the C/C++ flags, not linker...

Comment: That'll do it! I have put my information in a formal answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

clang and gcc support the `-rdynamic` option as a **linker** option. This should provide the ability for dladdr to function as expected in release mode. `-rdynamic` is defined as:

> **-rdynamic**
>   Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on targets that support it. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table. This option is needed for some uses of dlopen or to allow obtaining backtraces from within a program.

More information on gcc linker options can be  found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Comment: OP claims to have tried something similar but I think the option was being passed incorrectly.

Comment: Correct, the OP was passing it as *compiler* options. My first comment to his post was to try -rdyanmic as a *linker* option. I think that was when the OP clued in he had done the flag in the wrong place.